# Why service not start after BOOT_COMPLETED ?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I add my background service run perfectly but my phone switch off and switch on then my reciver class in get action android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.but service not start.my code below please help me!!!

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    static final String ACTION1 = "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Action :: "+intent.getAction());
         if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
                /* Setting the alarm here */
                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), + (1000 * 60 * 2), pendingIntent);
                Log.v("log_tag", "REPEAT");
            }
    }
```

And i also add permission in manifeast.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.employeemanager.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="***8"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="***.MyAlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="***.ReceiverCall"
            android:enabled="true"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="***" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Comment: Is your app on a SD card? Also when you put your receiver and service on your manifest, try to put the full package like : com.your.package.ReceiverCall and let me know if it works

Comment: Skizo i also add full package name add but nothing work.

Comment: See my answer please

Comment: you may miss to add  context.startService(alarmIntent);

Comment: let me know your result

Comment: @saeed Yep, he forgot that see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you misstyped but if you want to make that `Intent` work you should call :

```
context.startService(alarmIntent);
```

And let me know if this log `Log.v("log_tag", "Action :: "+intent.getAction());` is shown on your Logcat please this one `Log.v("log_tag", "REPEAT");` too.

I would suggest that your `BroadcastReceiver` will be like this :

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("log_tag", "Action :: "+intent.getAction());
     if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //make an intent to your Service as follows 
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
}
```

Then on your `Service` in your `onCreate` of your `Service` add this :

```
/* Setting the alarm here */
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, Whatever.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), + (1000 * 60 * 2), pendingIntent);
Log.v("log_tag", "REPEAT");
```

I would suggest also that you create a new `BroadcastReceiver` and on it do your stuff that you want to repeat, and replace the `whatever.class` by your `BroadccastReceiver`.

Comment: 12-31 17:00:48.645: V/log_tag(2473): Action :: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
12-31 17:00:48.649: V/log_tag(2473): REPEAT

Comment: Have you added `content.startService(alarmIntent);` ?

Comment: service started but not repeat after 2 min.

Comment: Ok, this is other problem the main issue is solved I guess :)

Comment: i want to  repeat service call every 2 min.

Answer (score 2):

A chance that your app is installed on external storage , it can't receive the boot completed event. You should add `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` in your manifest.